# GwtMockito: Is there a way to test Window.open()?

Tags: java, gwt, mockito, gwtmockito

I would like to test that my call of `Window.open(String)` is with the correct URL (to download a file).

Is there any better way of doing it, besides using a partial mock, like this?

```
MySUT sut = Mockito.spy(new MySUT());
String expectedURL = "http://www.example.com";

doNothing().when(sut).openWindow(expectedURL);

sut.doSomethingThatOpensURL();

verify(sut).openWindow(expectedURL);
```

Where `openWindow(String)` is as simple as possible in `MySUT`:

```
void openWindow(String url) {
    Window.open(url);
}
```

Does GwtMockito give you something to test methods that execute native javascript like `Window.open(String)`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no ability to verify it using *GwtMockito*. 
But I believe it's possible using *PowerMock* and *EasyMock*.
This mocking frameworks provide great flexibility to test static methods and 3rd party classes.

I've just created a simple example how you can test Window.open().
In my test case I'm just checking Window.alert(), for example.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Window.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.google.gwt.user.client.Window")
public class SimpleTester {

  /** Simple class for test. */
  private class TestClass {
    public void open(String url) {
      Window.alert(url);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    PowerMock.mockStatic(Window.class);

    TestClass obj = new TestClass();
    Window.alert("test");
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();
    PowerMock.replay(Window.class);

    obj.open("test");
    PowerMock.verify(Window.class);
  }
}
```